# Headers with similar functionality but different names

Tags: c++, header, cross-platform

I have common code on multiple platforms that relies on a header with certain function names to be `#include`d.

The problem is that the [more or less] same header has different names on each platform. I cannot simply rename the header on any platform as it's a standard `#include`. What is the recommended way to keep this common?

### Macros

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
   #include <platformA>
#endif

#ifdef PLATFORM_B
   #include <platformB>
#endif

//....
```

### Header Masking

In common code:

```
#include "common.h"
```

Platform A's "common.h":

```
#include <platformA>
```

Platform B's "common.h":

```
#include <platformB>
```

Or something else?

What are the pros/cons associated with each method, and in what instances should I use one over another?

Comment: I've seen both approaches many times.  They both seem reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'd combine both approaches. Instead of using method A over and over again in your code, making maintenance difficult, you should add one common header for each header which is platform dependent and use it to wrap the platform-specific includes:

**common_iostream.hpp:**

```
#ifndef COMMON_IOSTREAM_INC
#define COMMON_IOSTREAM_INC

#ifdef PLATFORM_A
#include <iostream>
#endif

#ifdef PLATFORM_B
#include <iostream.h>
#endif

#endif
```

That way you have a nice set of `common_*.hpp` headers and your code is kept clean, plus you don't have it split into different `platformA/common.hpp`, `platformB/common.hpp`, etc.

Comment: Well, of course I'd only do the ugly macro logic in one file, probably should've clarified that. But do you recommend this over including a "ghost file" that needs to be included per platform?

Comment: @ScottW I prefer it, but it's not a strong preference. And I haven't use it very often, only for about five or six headers in one of our company's projects (Linux, Solaris, MacOS, ~250.000 loc). Both approaches are reasonable and will work, just think about the maintenance aspect and what is appropriate for your environment.